# How to pass Multiple Class Object in $http Request

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, http, spring-mvc

My requirement is to pass multiple class object(which is going to map with request param or request body in rest controller) in angular $http service.

I can't pass class object in request body since one http call has only one request body.

When i'm trying to pass class object in $http param I'm getting class cast exception.

is there any way to pass multiple object in single $http call ??

```
@RequestMapping(value = "CommitObject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void Commit(@RequestParam(value = "clazz") final String clazz,
        @RequestParam(value = "Id") final String modelId,@RequestBody LinkedHashMap<String, Object> obj) {
    mService.Commit(Id,clazz workingmodelObj);
}
```

Comment: added code in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it many times but always failed.So to overcome this I use to create a  Java Bean and encapsulate both objects into it at then accepting it in     `@RequestBody`.

Your Wrapper should look like this:

```
public class SampleWrapper {
    private Object1 object1;
    private Object2 object2;
    //getters setters and constructors go here
}
```

And your constructor should look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url",method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String getRequest(@RequestBody SampleWrapper wrapper) {
    Object1 o1 = wrapper.getObject1();
    Object2 o2 = wrapper.getObject2();
}
```

JSON request should look like this:

```
 {
 "object1" : {//object1 body },
 "object2" : {//object2 body }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make a $http.post request you can make an array of the objects you are trying to send and then attach it in the request.

$http.put('ROUTE HERE', *Array Of Objects*);

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Objects by appending it in formData

**Angular side**

```
var formData=new FormData();
formData.append("obj1",new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj1)],{type: "application/json"}));
formData.append("obj2",new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj2)],{type: "application/json"}));
http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/MyProject/requestUrl',
     headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},//to set boundary value by default
     data: formData,
    })
```

**Spring side**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/requestUrl" }, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getRequest(@RequestPart("obj1") Object1 object1,
        @RequestPart("obj2") Object2 Object2,HttpSession session)
        throws IOException {

        //implementation
}
```

Comment: Actually I tried same approach but instead of using stringify I have created map of Object and passed it as Request body it's working absolutely fine all parameter are mapping to rest controller but when i try to cast Object (map.get(key)) into my java class I'm getting class cast exception